# How can i tell the VS2012 XamlEditor to stop parsing at design time

Tags: xaml, configuration, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to tell the VS2012 XamlEditor to stop parsing and creating at design time.

I use XAML (System.Xaml) to create configurations and other things, which do not have an UI, so the parsing at **design time** is useless for me.

I only want the XamlEditor for IntelliSense and auto completition.

Is it possible to do that? There is no need for the design view for me.